# Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{1\le i<j<k\le n} \sin\left(\frac{i+j+k}{n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Compute

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{1\le i<j<k\le n} \sin\left(\frac{i+j+k}{n}\right)$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac1{n^3} \sum_{1\le i<j<k\le n} \sin\left(\frac{i+j+k}{n}\right) & = \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac16 \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n \sin \left(\dfrac{i}n + \dfrac{j}n + \dfrac{k}n\right) \dfrac1{n^3}
\end{align}
Because each is a Riemann Sum, we can make this into an integral, when we take the limit. The above is true since the region $0 \leq x \leq y \leq z$ divides the unit cube into $1/6$ of the total region. The integral being symmetric should be the same in all six regions. There is a overlap on the boundaries but this is a measure zero set and hence won't affect the integral.
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac16 \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n \sin \left(\dfrac{i}n + \dfrac{j}n + \dfrac{k}n\right) \dfrac1{n^3} & = \dfrac16 \int_{[0,1]^3} \sin(x+y+z) dx dy dz\\
& = \dfrac43 \sin^4(1/2) (1+2 \cos(1))
\end{align}
We could have also directly converted this directly into the integral shown below without the $1/6$ factor i.e.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac1{n^3} \sum_{1\le i<j<k\le n} \sin\left(\frac{i+j+k}{n}\right) = \int_{z=0}^{z=1} \int_{y=0}^{y=z} \int_{x=0}^{x=y} \sin(x+y+z) dx dy dz$$
If you add in a factor of $\pi$ in your original expression i.e. 
$$\dfrac1{n^3} \sum_{1\le i<j<k\le n} \sin\left(\pi \left(\frac{i+j+k}{n} \right)\right) = - \dfrac{4}{3 \pi^3}$$

Comment: @Chris'ssister Have added the detail about the Riemann Sum.

Comment: In case, the factor $1/6$ is confusing, we could have also directly converted this directly into the integral shown below without the $1/6$ factor as I have shown now.

Comment: btw, do you know a generalization for this problem?

Comment: You mean in $d$ dimensions? i.e. $\dfrac1{n^d} \sin((i_1+i_2 + \cdots i_d)/n)$

Comment: Yes. I mean a generalization in $d$ dimensions.

Comment: @Chris'ssister If we consider the integral with $\pi$, my little conjecture would be for even dimensions, it will be zero and for odd dimensions it will be something like $$(-1)^{(d-1)/2} \dfrac{2^{(d+1)/2}}{(d!!)\pi^d}$$

Comment: It is interesting! Thank you for the details.

Comment: @Chris'ssister It may not be hard to prove but currently I do have the time.

Comment: It's OK. I don't need a generalization, but I was just curious about it and wanted to ask you since you also provided with nice generaliazations to other problems involving multiple sums.

Comment: @Chris'ssister he he :). Yes but unfortunately this time around, it may prove to involve too much time. Will try to address this for my own pleasure sometime later. Keep your wonderful interesting questions flowing!.

Comment: Thank you! And you keep providing with your very nice answers!:-)